# Elastic beanstalk .htaccess file not allowing specified IP through

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use a .htaccess file in the root of my PHP web app to block everything but my own static IP address, however it seems to be blocking everything and ignoring the exception. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <My IP>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do that through the [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html#using-features.managing.ec2.securitygroups)

You can check the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html): Just add a new rule for http/https where the source is your IP

Comment: I did try this approach as well, and I had the same problem in reverse - the security group let everything through instead of nothing.

Comment: hum ... The security group have inbound/outbound tab to identify incoming/outgoing traffic - add a new inbound rule and select MyIP from the dropdown box

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done for HTTP and HTTPS in one rule. Then I added it to the EC2 security groups properties of my web apps configuration and everything still seems to be going through when it shouldn't be.